# Ceiling Fan Won't Turn On Unless I Turn On The Recessed Lights Switch

Tags: wiring, lighting, light-fixture, ceiling-fan, recessed-lighting

I had a light fixture in the room. I took out the light fixture, and added four canned lights in the room, connected to where the light fixture was, and turning on and off using what was the light fixture on/off switch. Then, I decided to make use of the hole where the light fixture was and hang a  no-light ceiling fan. I ran a separate wire to the door and connected it to switch that came with the ceiling fan. And, (since the power from the breaker comes in at the hole where the light fixture was, not the switch), I connected the power for the ceiling fan through that before coming to the fan. However, the fan only works if I turn the can lights on. (The can lights work just fine, without the fan switch needing to be on though.) And, the fan turns on at High when I have the switch on Low, and when I put the switch up to High the fan slows down to Low. Does anybody have any ideas? Do I need to pull the fan further away on to its own series/circuit somehow? Maybe I shouldn't have given the fan its power by going THROUGH the main "bunny" hub where everything is connect. Maybe I should just go straight back to the fan, and then just do one additional wire that connects the fan to the "bunny" hub at the ceiling, but then the fan still has its own circuit/series?

Comment: Sounds like you have the line side of the fan switch hooked up to the load side of the light switch.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of all boxes involved please?

Comment: @JACK The Switch has its own wires, going from. the switch to the main “bunny” hub...